# R: Different range checks for different elements of a vector

Tags: r

Is there an R idiom for performing a different (integer) range check for each element of a vector?

My function is passed a two-element (integer) vector of the form `v = c(m, n)` and must make the following range checks:

1. 1 <= m <= M
2. 1 <= n <= N

For my current task, I've implemented them by manually accessing each element, and running the associated range check against it.

```
# Check if this is a valid position on an M x N chess board.
validate = function (square) {
    row = square[1]
    col = square[2]
    (row %in% 1:M) && (col %in% 1:N)
}
```

I wonder whether there's a compacter way of doing the range checks, especially if we were to generalize it to K-element vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're presumably setting up different criteria for each `v[j]`, I'd recommend creating a list out of your range criteria.  Like:

```
Rgames> set.seed(10)
Rgames> foo<-sample(1:5,5,rep=TRUE)
Rgames> foo
[1] 3 2 3 4 1
Rgames> bar<-list(one=1:5, two=3:5,three=1:3,four=c(2,4),five=c(1,4) )
Rgames> checkit<-NA
Rgames> for(j in 1:5) checkit[j]<-foo[j]%in%bar[[j]]
Rgames> checkit
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: This was the generalization I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, the inequality operators are vectorized in R, so you can make use of this fact.

```
limits <- c(M=3, N=4, 5)
v <- c(m=2, n=5, 8)
result <- 1 <= v & v <= limits
#    m     n       
# TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

And if you want a single value that's `FALSE` if any of the limits are exceeded, then you can wrap the inequality expression with `all`.

```
all(1 <= v & v <= limits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
`%between%` <- function(x,rng){
    all(x <= max(rng,na.rm = TRUE)) && all(x >= min(rng,na.rm = TRUE))
}

> 3 %between% c(1,10)
[1] TRUE
> 3:5 %between% c(1,10)
[1] TRUE
> 9:12 %between% c(1,10)
[1] FALSE
```

With tweaks depending on how you want to handle NAs, and other edge cases.